# How to copy folder from ubuntu to network in Terminal

Tags: ubuntu

I have ubuntu installed.
When i click on network i can see my windows computer shared folder.

Is there any command to copy folder `/home/testfolder`

on `/computername/sharedfolder`

The computer is available on ubuntu network

EDIT:

When i tried installing smbfs it get this

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  smbfs: Depends: samba-common (= 2:3.3.2-1ubuntu3) but 2:3.3.2-1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: You can try the `--fix-broken` option with `apt-get`

Comment: I tried but same error

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo smbmount //computername/sharedfolder /mnt/

cp /home/testfolder /mnt
```

Comment: THANKS FOR THAT , i got some error , i have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Use scp command.

scp -r /home/testfolder root@computername or ip :/sharedfolder